# Как установить chrome devtools autosave?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

Как ее на хром то поставить? [chrome-devtools-autosave](https://github.com/NV/chrome-devtools-autosave)

В faq написано зайти в `chrome://flags/` и включить Experimental Extension APIs, сделано.
Затем установить само приложение, сделано.

А дальше что? Дальше идет ссылка на инструкцию по установке его на сервер, но я работаю на денвере. В самом низу есть ответ для тех, кто работает на localhost'e

Но, черт возьми, что это значит?

```
If http://localhost/* corresponds to /Volumes/test/* you should create a config file (say routes.js):

exports.routes = [{
        from: /^http:\/\/localhost\//,
        to: '/Volumes/test/'
}];
and then run autosave --config routes.js
```

Создать js файл и в него вписать вот этот кусок кода? А куда потом этот файл пихать? И где прописывать "`autosave --config routes.js`"?
Dos не понимает этих команд

p.s. Я под виндой сижу.

Comment: вот полная статья как настроить https://goo.gl/LFYZ8g

Comment: @Павел спасибо за своевременный ответ, что такое 5 лет в сфере айти. только лишь мгновение :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ты работаешь на localhost, то в настройках расширения сделай как показано на рисунке
[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Здесь показано как я настроил на WAMP сервере. На денвере такие настройки могут не сработать так как денвер создает адрес сайта по-другому. Я уже не помню точно, но возможно нужно прописать ^http://localhost/www/

Comment: @napz, задан 26 Фев '12 14:43